Are there official scrabble dictionaries in other languages?
In English Scrabble there is a official list of words that are allowed to be played. Are there official lists for other languages that have officially licensed versions of scrabble?
All languages would be helpful for what I’m doing but the most important ones I would need are:

Bulgarian
Danish
Faroese
Greek
Icelandic
Norwegian
Russian
Spanish
Ukrainian


There are some shown in ScrabbleMania but I don't know if they are 'official'.

Most versions of the Scrabble rules distributed with the game reference either a "Standard Dictionary" of whatever language the game is published in, or indicate that the players should agree on which dictionary is to be used before play starts.
The most recent Hasbro update has changed the US English rules to indicate the Merriam-Webster Official SCRABBLE Players Dictionary (OSPD) should be used, but there is still a proviso that other dictionaries could be chosen:

You can play any word listed in The Official SCRABBLE Players Dictionary (or the dictionary of your choice)

That said each competitive Scrabble organisation has rules that define a lexicon to be used for determining the legality of a word during play.
These range from simple lists of words, to sets of rules for languages with more compounding.
Here's a selection of some of the more established Scrabble bodies and their official word sources



Organization
Region
** Lexicon **




WESPA (World English-Language Scrabble Players Association)
Global
Collins Scrabble Words (CSW)


NASPA (North American Scrabble Players Association)
United States, Canada
NASPA Word List (NWL)


WGPO (Word Game Players' Organization)
North America
NASPA Word List (NWL)


Fédération Française de Scrabble
France
L'Officiel du jeu Scrabble (ODS)


Federazione Italiana Gioco Scrabble
Italy
Zingarelli dizionari of the current year


Panhellenic Scrabble Association
Greece
ΟΡΟΙ ΑΠΟΔΟΧΗΣ ΛΕΞΕΩΝ


Federación Internacional de Scrabble en Español
Spain
FISE 2 Lexicon (uses a set of rules, not a list)


Polska Federacja Scrabble
Poland
Oficjalny słownik polskiego scrabblisty


Asociación Argentina de Scrabble
Argentina
Selected by the Comisión Directiva for each tournament (can have multiple sources)


Malaysian Scrabble Association
Malaysia
CSW


Association des Joueurs de Scrabble de Côte d'Ivoire
Côte d'Ivoire
L'Officiel du jeu Scrabble (ODS)


Nigerian Scrabble Federation (NSF)
Nigeria
CSW




Yes.
For example: French. The official dictionary is made by la FÉDÉRATION INTERNATIONALE de SCRABBLE® FRANCOPHONE.
The Amazon site for France has it for sale:
https://www.amazon.fr/LOfficiel-Scrabble%C2%AE-F%C3%A9d%C3%A9ration-Internationale-Scrabble/dp/2035962463
Similarly, the Federacion Internacional de Scrabble en Espanol has put out an official Spanish-language one.
There may be others for other languages, for sure.
